# What "things" is Roberto referring to?

Tags: marvel, new-mutants

High Sonic detected energy while Dani was dreaming about a deadly tornado.
The power tripped because of it so Roberto turned on the power:

> Roberto: You couldn't pay me a million dollars...to go in one of those
> **things**.
>
> Sam: I couldn't pay you a million dollars anyway. When we get out of
> here, I'll spot ya. My folks are good for it.

What "things" is Roberto referring to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just before the power tripped, they were talking in the same room before we briefly cut away to Dani causing the power surge.

> Roberto: Was it scary? Working in the mines?
>
> Sam: Yeah. Yeah, sure.

So it seems like after the momentary power blip
(which must occur often enough that they know exactly what to do and how to handle it instantly) they're not particularly bothered and so just continuing their previous conversation, so "those things" would be mines like the ones that Sam worked in.